# Running a Map Reduce Program in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I have a Map/Reduce program which loads a file and reads it into hbase. How do I execute my program through Eclipse? I googled and found 2 ways:

```
1) Using Eclipse Hadoop plugin
2) Create a jar file and execute it in Hadoop server
```

But, can I execute my Map/Reduce program by giving connection details and run in eclipse? Can any one tell me the exact procedure to run an Hbase Map/Reduce program?

Answer (score 0):

I have done the following:

- Installed and configured hadoop (and hdfs) on my machine
- Built a maven-ized java project with all of the classes for my hadoop job
- One of those classes is my "MR" or "Job" class that has a static main method that configures and submits my hadoop job
- I run the MR class in Eclipse as a java application

The job runs in hadoop using the libraries in the java project's classpath (and therefore doesn't show up in the job tracker).  Any reference to HDFS files uses the HDFS file system you installed and formatted using the non-eclipse hadoop install.

This works great with the debugger in Eclipse, although JUnit tests are kind of a pain to build by hand.